# How to show image in android app like facebook show in there app

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, imageview

I want to show photos in my application like Faceook shows. I want to add a GridView to show images as the no of images may be more than 1, so I want to show them in Grid. and there should be a image over which it can display the total number of images.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlUfl.jpg)

In the image you can see the arrangement of imageview, how to implement it android app?

Is any library or dependency is there for it?

Comment: Did you found any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Louvre Library](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5188)

Not the same as you want, but it is similar to that.

Comment: this library is just upload the image, my concern is to show the images in a  grid type layout, and grid should show only 5 pic at max after that it should show number of pics remaining like we see at facebook